# How to write dynamic data in firebase3 as a child node?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello everyone I am trying to write data to my firebase database. I have multiple "codes" that can be generated by the user and should be shown as seperate nodes inside a child node.

```
firebase.database().ref('users/').push({
                        user: uid,
                        titel: title,
                        codes: {
                          for(var i = 0;i < arrCodes.length;i++){
                            shareCode[i]: true,
                          }
                        },
                        enable: true,
                    });
```

the important part should look like this:

```
...
titel: title,
codes: {
 xksodkcisd: true,
 ksocjdiuvn: true,
 // and so on
},
enable: true,
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the loop outside the `.push()`?

```
var shareCodes = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arrCodes.length; i++) {
    shareCodes[i] = true;
}

firebase.database().ref('users/').push({
    user: uid,
    titel: title,
    codes: shareCodes,
    enable: true,
});
```